# scroll up to the soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a long form and when the soft keyboard appear I can't see the bottom editTexts

This is my xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/username" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_username"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_edit_username"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_edit_password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/confirm" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_confirm"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_mail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_edit_confirm"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/mail" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_mail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_mail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_edit_mail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_phone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_last_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_edit_phone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/last_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_last_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_last_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_first_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_edit_last_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/first_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_first_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_first_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_alert_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_edit_first_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/register_alert_pwd" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_alert_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_alert_password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_alert_password_confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_edit_alert_password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/register_alert_pwd_confirm" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_alert_password_confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_alert_password_confirm"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >
    </EditText>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/register_tou"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_edit_alert_password_confirm"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/register_tou" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register_valid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_tou"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/confirm" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I also update my activity in the manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="my name"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
</activity>
```

In all others posts I saw the solution was

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

But it don't works in my case

Thanks

**Edit**

Update to my last code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/register"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/username" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/confirm" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_mail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/mail" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_mail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_last_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/last_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_last_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_first_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/first_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_first_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_alert_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/register_alert_pwd" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_alert_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_alert_password_confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/register_alert_pwd_confirm" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_edit_alert_password_confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >
    </EditText>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/register_tou"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/register_tou" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_condition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/register_read_tou" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register_valid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/confirm" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: use adjustPan instead of adjustResize.

Comment: Thanks but I always have the same problem

Comment: If you have a long form you should really have it in a ScrollView to begin with. No guarantee your user will have the screen height to see it all, with or without the keyboard. If you do that, they'll just be able to scroll down when the keyboard pops up.

Comment: yes, all my code is in a ScrollView

Comment: I downloaded your code and reproduced the problem. It happens only in FULLSCREEN style, even when setted programmatically. It looks like some buggy because the viewport doesn't scrolls to very botton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah.. Fullscreen mode doesn't resize :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7509285/1499064

If you don't use fullscreen the adjustPan and everything else will work

Answer (score 1):

You could try this in your manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified"
```

I have that in my app that is in a `ScrollView` and it works for me. I think that that may also be the defualt value for `windowSoftInputMode` but I'm not 100% sure.

Edit: Here is the beginning of my `ScrollView`, unchanged.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity"
     android:id="@+id/testing">
```

Maybe try to put your `LinearLayout` height as `match_parent` as well.

Comment: Also, you may want to consider changing your `fill_parent`'s to `match_parent`. `fill_parent` was deprecated in API 8 and replaced with `match_parent`.

Comment: I update my manifest and change fill_parent to match_parent but I have the same result

Comment: I don't think I need the `xmlns` tag in both the `ScrollView` and the `RelativeLayout`. This was from when I had just begun to learn Android.

Comment: I have a warning using a match_parent on a LinearLayout and I have the same problem

Comment: Wow... this is really odd. I feel like this shouldn't be this difficult... I'll try to think about this some more and get back if I can think of anything.

Comment: Just to exhaust all possibilities, maybe you could try to model your `ScrollView` after mine and change the `LinearLayout` back to `RelativeLayout`.... Just a shot in the dark here. I'm just really confused since I know that this is what worked for me, I don't see why it shouldn't work for others...

Comment: Ok, I think that I solve my problem, I have the problem on a tablet wbt it works on a mobile.

Comment: Awesome! What fixed it on the mobile? Also, I have this code working on a Nexus 7 if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your scroll view:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

and I think in Manifest the following setting

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

will do its work right.

Comment: I add android:fillViewport="true" to my scroll view and update my activity in my manifest whit only adjustResize but I alwayd have the same problem, I can't scroll to the bottom of the page is hide by the keyboard and I can't scroll above the keyboard

Comment: @burrows111 Yes without using fullscreen